# What are the advantages of using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (a.k.a. ADAM) over a custom-rolled authentication & access scheme?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, authentication

I'm having a discussion with out internal developers on using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services instead of custom-rolling our own scheme to manage authentication and access to our application. They think it will be more complicated / time consuming to use AD LDS and also that AD LDS will be less configurable (flexible) than a custom solution.

I don't see why. I understand with AD LDS you can deploy your own schema.

Our app (C#, ASP.net) will need to authenticate via Web services and Web pages.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually just finished a project to integrate the company's application to an Active Directory. It was pretty simple and painless.

You should go for AD. It's very simple to authenticate a user via C# code (at least from .NET 3.5 on). And you will gain the great advantage of having a single authentication repository for multiple applications.

Look here for a few examples: [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-Csharp-NET-3-5-.aspx?display=Mobile)

As you can see, you can validate credential in 5 to 6 lines of code. Also, it is worth looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx), Microsoft's page on AD handling in .NET 3.5.

Comment: @ Adrian The OP is asking about **AD LDS** as opposed to vanilla AD. IME there is *significant* spade work that needs to be done to get AD LDS up and running. I agree wholeheartedly though with your comments on ActiveDirectory.